# Liferay: PDF saving filename

Tags: pdf, liferay

I can serve PDF files no problem with Liferay but when I try to save them they just get the filename from the url like such:

```
http://localhost:8080/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=7a75925d-77f6-4d8a
```

In this case when hitting the Save button in the Acrobat reader plugin the suggested filename will be **get_file**. Any idea on how to preserve the original file name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)